# Raid 5 array won't assemble after 1 drive's partition table was wiped

Tags: raid5, partition-table

This is my first post/question here, so please bear with me.

I have an issue with my system where my existing raid5 array won't assemble. This occurred after I inadvertently wiped the partition table of the first disk in the array.

The system was set up a while ago with two raid arrays across 4 identical 4Tb disks - a 2Tb effective/4Tb disk space raid 1 array (md0), intended for home backups, and an ~8Tb effective/12Tb disk space raid 5 array (md1) for media storage.

I was trying to extract all the data from the system to wipe the arrays and start again, so I had removed all data from the Raid 1 array and deleted the array in webmin. I then went into partition manager in webmin intending to change the 1Tb partition on the first drive from part of the now-gone md0 to a usable drive. Unfortunately, doing so wiped the partition table for the whole disk.

So now I am left with a scenario where md1 is showing as inactive in webmin, and I don't know what the best way forward is. Can I "recreate" the raid partitions on sda and have it add back to md1? or can I force md1 to assemble from the remaining 3 drives, and continue the existing data transfer process?
the output of

```
sudo mdadm -D /dev/md1
```

is

```
/dev/md1:
       Version : 1.2
    Raid Level : raid5
 Total Devices : 3
   Persistence : Superblock is persistent

         State : inactive
Working Devices : 3

          Name : miranda:1  (local to host miranda)
          UUID : 3d6bf0c4:16037750:01681844:95415c3d
        Events : 2086

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

   -       8       50        -        /dev/sdd2
   -       8       34        -        /dev/sdc2
   -       8       18        -        /dev/sdb2
```

Using `lsblk`

gives

```
sda       8:0    0   3.6T  0 disk
sdb       8:16   0   3.6T  0 disk
├─sdb1    8:17   0 931.5G  0 part
└─sdb2    8:18   0   2.7T  0 part
  └─md1   9:1    0     0B  0 md
sdc       8:32   0   3.6T  0 disk
├─sdc1    8:33   0 931.5G  0 part
└─sdc2    8:34   0   2.7T  0 part
  └─md1   9:1    0     0B  0 md
sdd       8:48   0   3.6T  0 disk
├─sdd1    8:49   0 931.5G  0 part
└─sdd2    8:50   0   2.7T  0 part
  └─md1   9:1    0     0B  0 md
```

The data on these drives isn't critical, but it would be preferable to be able to recover/access them than not.

Comment: Hi, can you add results of "cat /proc/mdstat" 
and also what happen if you run mdam --start /dev/md1 ?

You probably just play around with the mdraid, but for real systems it's not a good idea to use one physical disk in two arrays, because it reduces raids redundancy and can be a reason of performance issues if your configuration is based on HDDs.

Comment: @AleksandrMakhov 
So ```cat /proc/mdstat``` gives the following

```Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md1 : inactive sdd2[3](S) sdc2[2](S) sdb2[1](S)
      8790398976 blocks super 1.2```

using ```mdadm --start /dev/md1``` returns "unrecognized option '--start' "

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I was able to get the array to work by using the command

`mdadm --run /dev/md1`

Once I confirmed that it was all happy and accessible, I used the partition information from the 3 good disks to "repartition" the disk that I accidentally wiped the table from, then added it back into the array. I must have got the apportionment slightly off, because it had to rebuild, but it did so successfully overnight without any data loss.